# Merging Pandas Dataframe with no duplicated columns on one key

Tags: pandas, dataframe, join, duplicates, outer-join

I am new to Pandas and have tried reviewing different solutions on here but I am having some issues with joining two data frames. They are joining ok, however for some for some columns I would like it to to remain as NULL instead of duplicating

Sample DF1

| employee | year |
| --- | --- |
| x12345 | 2023 |
| x12345 | 2022 |
| z12345 | 2015 |
| z12345 | 2013 |

Sample DF2

| employee | status |
| --- | --- |
| x12345 | active |
| z12345 | active |
| m12345 | inactive |
| q12345 | active |

What I have tried

merged = pd.merge(DF1, DF2, how="outer", on=["employee"]

What I currently have

| employee | year | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x12345 | 2023 | active |
| x12345 | 2022 | active |
| z12345 | 2015 | active |
| z12345 | 2013 | active |

What I need

| employee | year | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x12345 | 2023 | active |
| x12345 | 2022 | NULL |
| z12345 | 2015 | active |
| z12345 | 2013 | NULL |

What I have tried

merged = pd.merge(DF1, DF2, how="outer", on=["employee"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code**

```
df1.assign(key=df1.groupby('employee').cumcount())\
   .merge(df2.assign(key=df2.groupby('employee').cumcount()), how='left')\
   .drop('key', axis=1)
```

out:

```
employee    year    status
0   x12345  2023    active
1   x12345  2022    NaN
2   z12345  2015    active
3   z12345  2013    NaN
```